# Junit, Selenium, and NoClassDefFound

Tags: eclipse, macos, junit, selenium-webdriver

I feel like a complete newb here. I recently switch to using a Mac for development and i'm running into problems with some of my projects. I feel like its a class pathing issue within the macs classpath not eclipse build path... Here goes. ..

Selenium project with Junit.

I attempt to compile and:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
at Login.testLoginPage(Login.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 20 more
```

I have scoured the forums and i can't seem to resolve. I have the libs added to my project. When i use MAVEN (outside the base project) the pom.xml imports the dependencies correctly and runs (i'm not using Maven though). I compared what the maven pom.xml is importing to what my original project has imported, and the jars are identical.  here is an abbreviated list...

- apache-mime4j
- bsh-1.3.0
- cglib-nodep-2.1_3
- commons-codec-1.6
- commons-collections-3.2
- commons-exec-1.1
- commons-io-2.2
- commons-jxpath-1.3
- commons-lang3
- commons-logging-1.1.1
- cssparser-0.9.8
- guava-14.0
- hamcrest-core
- hamcrest-library-1.3
- htmlunit-2.11
- ....
- ....
- ....
- selnium-java-2.31.0
- junit-4.11
- ....

I can take the exact same project and import it on my old windows machine and it compiles/runs without any issues.  Any help here would be **MOST** appreciated! Man i feel like this shouldn't be this painful... I feel like i overlooked something.  or quite frankly it could be the mac and my new-ness.

Comment: additional info.. I found for whatever reason i have in my /Library/Java/Extention directory references to the selenium source jar.  If i remove that, eclipse returns an error:

Description Resource Path Location Type
The container 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]' references non existing library '/Library/Java/Extensions/selenium-java-2.31.0-srcs.jar   I have no idea why this is occurring.  I tried on a different mac the same setup, download eclipse, download the respected jars, etc. and the project fired right off... any ideas?

Comment: Download Selenium server file from this link http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar  and then add it to the lib.

Comment: HemChe i already have the jar added to the project it doesn't change the compilation or the fact that i have this /Library/Java/Extention dependency (however that happened!).

Answer (score 0):

I had to recreate my jre6 installed runtime within Eclipse.

done by clicking Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE

then adding my JRE back.